# Here Premium Android SDK - Duplicate class a.a.a.a found in modules jetified-HERE-sdk-runtime.jar

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

Not sure how to fix this issue but it's throwing alot of duplicate class errors

```
Duplicate class a.a.a.a found in modules jetified-HERE-sdk-runtime.jar
```

I've follow the guide

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.17/dev_guide/topics/app-create-simple.html

added the dependencies

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')
}
```

And have also added

HERE-sdk.aar into my libs folder but it still is giving me all these errors..

I've had no problem using the Here Explorer SDK

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue solved by creating a new project with the exact same code.
I tried invalidating caches, closing project and reopening but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
-repackageclasses 'com.your.package'
```

Add this rule in the proguard file, a.a.a.a duplicate issue get resolve.

ProGuard will rename the classes and resources within the specified package to obfuscate them. This helps to make the code more difficult to understand and reverse engineer, improving the security of your Android application.